# How to I extend a base class and implement an interface using Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am using the Eclipse JDT library.

```
import cfjapa.parser.ast.body.ModifierSet;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ITypeHierarchy;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AST ast = AST.newAST(AST.JLS13, true);
        CompilationUnit unit = ast.newCompilationUnit();

        // set strategy pattern package name
        PackageDeclaration packageDeclaration = ast.newPackageDeclaration();
        packageDeclaration.setName(ast.newSimpleName("strategy"));
        unit.setPackage(packageDeclaration);

        // define strategy interface
        TypeDeclaration type = ast.newTypeDeclaration();
        type.setInterface(Boolean.TRUE);
        type.modifiers().add(ast.newModifier(Modifier.ModifierKeyword.PUBLIC_KEYWORD));
        type.setName(ast.newSimpleName("Strategy"));

        // define strategy interface method
        MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration = ast.newMethodDeclaration();
        methodDeclaration.setConstructor(false);
        List modifiers = methodDeclaration.modifiers();
        modifiers.add(ast.newModifier(Modifier.ModifierKeyword.PUBLIC_KEYWORD));
        methodDeclaration.setName(ast.newSimpleName("algorithmInterface"));
        methodDeclaration.setReturnType2(ast.newPrimitiveType(PrimitiveType.VOID));

        type.bodyDeclarations().add(methodDeclaration);
        unit.types().add(type);


        System.out.println(unit);

    }
}
```

Now I would like another class to implement the above interface `Strategy`.
How can I accomplish this?

I Can't find any good examples in the documentation.

Comment: Standard Eclipse JDT does not support this. [Eclipse Object Teams](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.objectteams) might do what you want

Comment: Any concrete examples using Eclipse Object Teams?

Comment: Did you asked the [same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60219421/6505250)? Is the code of JDT UI not enough example of how to use JDT core?

Comment: I don't know anymore than it says on the website

Comment: An answer moved to a better fitting question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60170365/is-eclipses-ecj-compiler-extensible/60239288#60239288

Comment: Indeed for this question I see no reason why JDT API should be insufficient :) In particular class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.codemanipulation.StubUtility2Core should provide plenty of ideas.